# Css file not linking with html/php file

Tags: php, html, css

I have looked over the code and cant seem to see where the link between the two files is failing. My index page uses the exact same code to link the files and it works fine. When I add the styling in the header of the php/html file it works but otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: What is your folder/file structure?  Is the css file in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: @dsadnick  All stored in the docs file of mamp. So yes all the files are in the same folder

Comment: (Similar to the folder structure question) Have you opened this page with a browser's debugger (like Firebug) running?  If the problem is along the lines of "I can't find the file" or "I can't parse the file", it should show up in the debugger console.

Comment: I for one don't see any php here.

Comment: how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">` (with slash).

Comment: if your style.css is in css folder- you should add something like `href="css/style.css"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- localhost

Comment: see what error reporting says then http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and what's the file extension for the file that isn't working? again; I don't see any "php" in your posted code.

Comment: ok; you've a new answer below. This question is starting to attract more answers that don't seem to solve your issue. I am moving on now, I wish you well with this. If you have any further information to share (with me); you can ping. I sincerely wish you well.

Answer (score 0):

The reference that you have for the stylesheet is relative to the url of the page you're on.

For example, this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

... says that the stylesheet is at the same path that the page is on. So if the url in the address bar is https://somewebsite/admin/index.php then that page will try to load the stylesheet at https://somewebsite/admin/style.css. If the url is https://somewebsite/index.php then the page will try to load the stylesheet at https://somewebsite/style.css.

If the stylesheet resides at the root of the site then your link tag should look like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">`

This will make your page look for the stylesheet at https://somewebsite/style.css regardless of what the path of the url says.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the right path, right into your css file at

Example:

```
<link href="assets/css/blabla.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: you should pay attention to comments everywhere before posting.